# How to do remote JNLP error reporting?

Tags: java, eclipse, build, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I have a `JNLP` downloader application deployed on remote user machines that downloads files. 
I need to get some error feedback mailed to me. Not so much `exceptions`, just things getting stuck, or stalled or in infinite loops.

Currently I have a basic handler:

```
 import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;

 public class javaerrorlog {
 private static Logger l = Logger.getLogger("");

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{ 
   FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("log.txt");
  l.addHandler(handler);

  l.setLevel(Level.ALL);

  l.info("Error logs");
   try {

   } catch (Error ex) {
   l.log(Level.INFO, "", ex);
   }
   l.fine("");
   }
 }
```

Also, should I prompt for the client's permission to send error reporting data?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need notifications you could use something like [SMTPHandler](http://smtphandler.sourceforge.net/). If you need it more fancy you could use JMS with an MDB.

Comment: Thanks I found bug4j haven't got it working but it's installed and seems to be working on the localhost